How to acquire JButton's enabled state at runtime from another class
I have multiple forms containing multiple textFields and a save JButton each. When I create each of these fields, i pass the form's save button to the associated InputVerifiers which are supposed to

acquire save button's enabled state at that particular time (when cursor enters the textfield)
check text input against certain conditions and set/reset the success flag accordingly
at the end, change the enabled state of the save JButton to its initial state andded with the current success flag

The idea is that if the save button was disabled due to some previous field's non-compliance, it should remain disabled even now, no matter whether the current textfield's input is compliant or not, but if the button was in enabled state when the cursor entered the current textfield, the JButton's state should be enabled if current tests pass, disabled otherwise.
My question is how to transfer the reference of the JButton to the InputVerifiers so that they can acquire its live state. Right now i'm just passing the button object and InputVerifier stores its state in the constructor so obviously this state is the button's state at compile-time.
EDIT: Following is the minimalist code:
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AddChannel extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField txtLo, txtHi;

    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { dispose(); } 

    public AddChannel() {
        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Add New Record");
        btnSave.addActionListener(this);
    
        JLabel lblMsg = new JLabel("       "); // create b4 utilizing in InputVerifiers
        lblMsg.setForeground(Color.RED);
    
        JLabel lblLo = new JLabel("Low Operating Range: ");
        JLabel lblHi = new JLabel("High Operating Range: ");
    
        txtLo = new JTextField("");
        txtLo.setInputVerifier(new ActionFloatVerifier(lblMsg, btnSave, "Low Range"));
    
        txtHi = new JTextField("");
        txtHi.setInputVerifier(new ActionFloatVerifier(lblMsg, btnSave, "High Range"));
    
        JPanel pnlFields = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4, 10, 15));
        pnlFields.add(lblLo);
        pnlFields.add(txtLo);
        pnlFields.add(lblHi);
        pnlFields.add(txtHi);

        JPanel pnlButtons = new JPanel();
        pnlButtons.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlButtons, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pnlButtons.add(lblMsg);

        pnlButtons.add(btnSave);
    
        setSize(new Dimension(600, 120));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(pnlFields, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(pnlButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new AddChannel();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ActionFloatVerifier extends InputVerifier {
    private JTextField txtField;
    private JLabel lblError;
    private JButton btnSave;
    private String fieldName;

    public ActionFloatVerifier (JLabel lbl, JButton btn, String field) {
        lblError = lbl;
        btnSave = btn;
        fieldName = field;
    }

    @Override public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        txtField = (JTextField) input;
        String newText = txtField.getText().strip();
        if (!newText.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                Float.parseFloat(newText.trim()); // just try to parse!
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                lblError.setText("Enter a valid float value for " + fieldName);
                return doTheDue(false);
            }
        }

        return doTheDue(true);
    }

    private boolean doTheDue(boolean ok) {
        txtField.setForeground(ok? Color.BLACK : Color.RED);
        lblError.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblError.setVisible(!ok);

        btnSave.setEnabled(ok && btnSave.isEnabled()); // if ok, return btn to original state that the btn was initially in
        // i.e. if initially disabled (due to some previous error) then should be disabled even now

        return ok;
    }
}


Add InputVerifiers as a PropertyChangeListener to the button(s)

Could InputVerifier not just store the JButton itself? Then you can just query the button about its state.

@MTilsted: I tried it as I'm already passing the button object but once any of the current tests fails, it turns button's state to disabled and when the user next tries to move to the next field after correcting the input, it keeps the button disabled as its current state is disabled due to previous error whereas the initial state when user entered current field, was enabled so the output state should have been enabled.

Please consider creating and posting a decent [mre] with  your question so that we can experience your problem directly and clearly.

@Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Minimal code added

You need a way to track whether all of the fields are valid.  Pass a Set<JComponent> invalidComponents to your InputVerifier.  You could then have something like if (ok) invalidComponents.remove(input); else invalidComponents.add(input); btnSave.setEnabled(invalidComponents.isEmpty());

@VGR: I can't use this approach because I want that each field's data is validated as soon as the user tries to leave that field bcoz it's possible that the user enters an invalid value and directly clicks the Save button without entering other values. I can't let it happen.

I’m not clear on why you can’t use it.  That code would be in the InputVerifier’s verify method.

There are at least 7 different kinds of InputVerifiers (on the pattern of ActionFloatVerifier) that I'm using to verify multiple types of fields. And on each form, the combination of InputVerifiers is different. The code included here is just a small representation of the big scenario.

@g00se: Any insight on how to use PropertyChangeListener on buttons in my scenario where I need to get button's current enabled state on focusLost() event of textFields (i.e. within InputVerifiers)...??

I have multiple forms containing multiple textFields and a save JButton each. Firstly, since the 'verifiers' are verifying these forms, why aren't they private inner classes of these forms? That would surely be the place for them and they would already have access to the form's components

InputVerifers are independent, public classes because they're being used in multiple forms. The idea is that an InputVerifier should get as input a textField, a button and a label. It should then verify the contents of the textField. If error, it should notify the user via label and disable the button, and if verified the label should simply be hidden and button should turn enabled if it was enabled when user first entered this field and should turn disabled if it was disabled at that time....

At what point do you need to know the state - is it at Verifier::doTheDue?

Exactly! At btnSave.setEnabled(ok && btnSave.isEnabled()); point... But here the problem is that if user entered txtField with button enabled, and entered invalid input, the button would turn disabled and user will be guided to correct the input. Now when he corrects the input and leaves the field, now the current state of button is disabled due to which the output state of button remains disabled while it should be enabled.

Well, now that I'm bringing my problem into writing, i think i've found the logical error that I'm making. I simply need to store the initial state of the button and AND the validation result with that instead of current state.... But when I was doing that before posting here, there was some other erroneous behavior that I can't recall now

I don't really understand why the verifier wouldn't be called again when the input is good
